# Function of two cells

Tags: vba, excel

What is wrong about:

```
Function Muh(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
   Muh = a + b
End Function
```

and table with say A1=2 and B1=3 an defining C1=Muh(A1,B1)?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: Technically I do not see anything wrong with the code. What error are you getting?

Comment: @pnuts: In a Modul

Comment: @SiddharthRout: A pop-up Window told me that the formula was wrong, and left me with standard instructions about how to type a formula.

Comment: negative vote? was the question unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the comma with a semicolon

```
C1=Muh(A1;B1)
```